# How to export multiple components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm creating an Angular 2 library for npm and id like to allow the user to implement all of the components in one import statement.

Like for instance when importing `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';

directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Put them all in the same file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If i just writ export class component1 {} and export class component2{}. You would still need to write import {component1, component2} from 'path'

Comment: Oh, you want the ROUTER_DIRECTIVES behavior. `export var MY_DIRECTIVES = [ DirectiveOne, DirectiveTwo ];`

Comment: So simple thank you very much.

Comment: Can you add your comment as answer, so i can mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the components in an array and export that array:

```
export var MY_DIRECTIVES = [ DirectiveOne, DirectiveTwo ];
```

And you'll be able to import that array:

```
import { MY_DIRECTIVES } from 'your/file';
```